# Luggage transfer within the EU on international + domestic flights

Tags: air-travel, luggage, europe, airlines, eu

Is it possible for a two-legged flight which starts in France and ends in Poland (or more generally - starts and ends within the EU) to have a luggage checked-in all the way if the first flight is international and the other is domestic?

In other words if I fly Paris - Warsaw - Cracow on a single LOT ticket (both boarding passes will be issued at the same time) can I check in my luggage in Paris and get it back in Cracow (without the need to handle it in Warsaw)?

UPDATE: they were finally checked-in for the whole flight (the international an domestic legs)

Comment: There are at least no EU wide rules. When flying to Sweden, it depends both on the airline, the first and the final airport if you have to clear customs at the first or final airport.

Comment: I called the airline to check (which probably should have been the first thing to do...) - they assure me that this will be possible and is standard for flights on one reservation (also with a stopover). I am sure, per @Tor-EinarJarnbjo comment that this may be dependent on countries/airlines/airports though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (in this particular circumstance). Within most of the EU your bag will be checked to its final destination without distinction between domestic or international flights. This applies even if the final airport does not have customs inspections facilities (but very few airports in Europe completely lack these facilities).

You are still responsible for making an appropriate customs declaration, either at the final airport or when you first enter the country in question.

The exception is within the Scandinavian countries where a customs inspection may be applied at entry to Scandinavia.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, on a single ticket/booking - your luggage is checked all the way to the destination.  This holds true for flights out-in-through the EU; and elsewhere.

This holds true even if you are flying on two different carriers (under a code-share flight).

If there are any exceptions, you will be informed of them at check-in time.

A notable exception (which doesn't apply to your situation) is the US - where you have to clear immigration at the first port of entry **even if you are in transit and your final destination isn't in the US**.  Your checked-in luggage is also unloaded (even if its checked in all the way to your final destination). You have to manually pick up your luggage and drop it at the baggage carousel (these are clearly marked) and then continue on your journey.

Comment: The US is not an exception. Every country outside Europe applies a full customs inspection by unloading checked baggage and presenting it for inspection when first entering their country. (Are there any exceptions?) I think the real exception to normal is Europe.

Comment: @Calchas In the Schengen area you usually clear customs at your destination country, though for an itinerary entirely inside the EU such as this one, you simply walk through the blue channel (which is why it's there).

Comment: @Calchas in the US - even if you are **transiting** you have to clear customs and immigration. This, afaik is unique to the US. In the UK and many EU countries, some nationalities need a visa for transit and this is validated at immigration counters, but your baggage is not unloaded.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid But this question is about international to domestic transits. Also some US airports (MIA, DFW, ATL) can handle checked-through baggage to international destinations without customs inspection of that baggage (called "ITI"), although I accept this is a little rare.